# Prevent bootstrap dropdown from opening if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap text input group with dropdown for live search results, by default dropdown opens when you click on textbox.  I like you have dropdown not show up until there are "li" tags in there.  how can i go about doing that?
below is my html for search bar.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="GET" action="/search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control searchbar" placeholder="Quick search..." name="q" data-toggle="dropdown" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="checkTextField();">

    <ul class="dropdown-menu search_results" style="width:100%" role="menu">
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

I tried below jquery but didn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$myList = $('.search_results') 
if ( $myList.children().length === 0 ) 
{ $('.search_results').hide(); 
} 
});
```

Comment: Can you use jquery, javascript, or something similar to solve this problem?

Comment: yes i can, thats actually what i need help with, i did $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $myList = $('.search_results')
    
    if ( $myList.children().length === 0 )
    {
         $('.search_results').hide();
    }
});  but that doesn't work

Comment: @max please use the edit-function to include all code in your question. Please don't post code in the comments, that's unreadable

Comment: you want show only matching li after type in input, right?

Comment: yes im going to be using algolia for my search engine so when user starts typing, ill get ajax response of results and ill populate dropdown with the results as li tags

Comment: can you please add your ajax code

Comment: that part is not done yet, right now im trying to keep dropdown from opening when i click on the text input.  by default small dropdown menu still pops up when i click on text input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle event on input. Then check for child & hide `ul`

```js
$('.searchbar').on('click', function (event) {
   if($(".search_results").children().length<=0){
    $(".search_results").hide();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="GET" action="/search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control searchbar" placeholder="Quick search..." name="q" data-toggle="dropdown" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="checkTextField(event);">

    <ul class="dropdown-menu search_results" style="width:100%" role="menu">
    </ul>

    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: maybe you have childs inside `ul`

Comment: if you have `checkTextField()` function try after removing that

Comment: i don't have that function

Comment: yes i did exactly same thing, Instead of hide() i tried console.log() but nothing is logging.  so there is problem somewhere else.  and i noticed when i click on text input and dropdown shows up. its adding "open" class to input-group div

Comment: you need to hide that dont remove that it ll work or just craete another file add this code only and test

Comment: yes i tried, same code you posted on clean project, it still shows empty dropdown menu.  i put console.log() inside if statement. and its not triggering so something is wrong there.

Comment: it finally worked when I used search_results as id and not class

Comment: may be you have another class with same name